# How to customize JAX-WS RuntimeException responses?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, jax-ws-customization

I am trying to customize the fault responses for `RuntimeException`s thrown before reaching to the `WebMethod`, like invalid xml body or wrong method name  for a JAX-WS service.
I tried to use a handler with `@HandlerChain` but the response is sent before processed by the handler.

Here is an example. Lets say i have a method copyTool method in my ws but client sent below request. I want to be able to customize the response so that i can change the faultString or return some custom faultCode.

**Input**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:cor="http://acme.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <cor:copyTool>
       <toolNumber>some Text instead of Integer</toolNumber>
      </cor:copyTool>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Output**

```
    <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns0:Fault xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
         <faultcode>ns0:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Exception Description: The object [some Text instead of Integer], of class [class java.lang.String], from mapping [org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[toolNumber-->toolNumber/text()]] with descriptor [XMLDescriptor(com.acme --> [DatabaseTable(ns0:copyTool)])], could not be converted to [class java.lang.Integer].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "some Text instead of Integer"</faultstring>
      </ns0:Fault>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Comment: Can you provide a codebase so that it can be test and resolved easily?

Comment: @AnishB. You can try with most basic JAXWS setup

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try with an ExceptionMapper as follows:

```
@Provider
public class WebApplicationExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception>{

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Exception exception) {
        Response.Status responseStatus = THE_STATUS_YOU_WANT_BASED_ON_THE_EXCEPTION;
        return Response.status(responseStatus).entity(THE_ERROR_ENTITY_YOU_WANT_BASED_ON_THE_EXCEPTION).build();
    }

}
```

Comment: I guess this only works for jax-rs services.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to customize the fault message via `@HandlerChain` for `RuntimeException`. I guess you did something wrong.

**Step - by - Step process on what I did to make it working:**

I have created a sample project to demonstrate.

**Project Structure (Maven Project):**

[image]

**pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>customize-fault-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**PublishLotteryService:**

```
package org.example.endpoint;

import org.example.webservice.LotteryServiceImpl;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class PublishLotteryService {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/webservice/lottery", new LotteryServiceImpl());
    }

}
```

**LotteryService (A WebService Interface):**

```
package org.example.webservice;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Use;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT, use = Use.LITERAL)
public interface LotteryService {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "SendYourNameAndWinLottery")
    String sendYourNameAndWinLottery(String nameOfThePerson);

}
```

**LotteryServiceImpl (A WebService Implementation):**

```
package org.example.webservice;

import javax.jws.HandlerChain;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "org.example.webservice.LotteryService")
@HandlerChain(file = "custom-fault-message.xml")
public class LotteryServiceImpl implements LotteryService {

    @Override
    public String sendYourNameAndWinLottery(String nameOfThePerson) {
        return "Hi, " + nameOfThePerson + ". You are one of the lucky winners. You won a $1000 USD.";
    }
}
```

**Note:** You have to tell your WebService to use the `@HandlerChain` via creating a handler chain **.xml** file with any name and setting/referring that **.xml** file into the `@HandlerChain`.

**custom-fault-message.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<javaee:handler-chains 
     xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <javaee:handler-chain>
    <javaee:handler>
      <javaee:handler-class>org.example.handler.CustomizeFaultMessageHandler</javaee:handler-class>
    </javaee:handler>
  </javaee:handler-chain>
</javaee:handler-chains>
```

**CustomizeFaultMessageHandler:**

```
package org.example.handler;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPFault;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext;
import java.util.Set;

public class CustomizeFaultMessageHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        try {
            SOAPBody body = context.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getBody();
            SOAPFault soapFault = body.getFault();
            soapFault.setFaultCode("random-code");
            soapFault.setFaultString("place your custom error message here.");
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext context) {
    }

    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

**Few things to be noted which are important:**

You have to set `return true;` from `false` in the `handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context)`. Otherwise, it won't go into `handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context)` to handle `Fault` related things.

Now, you can see this code :

```
SOAPBody body = context.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope().getBody();
SOAPFault soapFault = body.getFault();
soapFault.setFaultCode("random-code");
soapFault.setFaultString("place your custom error message here.");
```

Just I'm getting the default `Fault` and overriding it with my custom **Fault Code** and **Fault Message** here. Now, the current `SOAPMessageContext` is updated with the Fault containing my custom values. That's all you have to do.

**Output (Success Case):**

**Input XML Request Payload :**

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <SendYourNameAndWinLottery xmlns="http://webservice.example.org/">
            <arg0 xmlns="">Anish</arg0>
        </SendYourNameAndWinLottery>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

**Output XML Response:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:SendYourNameAndWinLotteryResponse xmlns:ns2="http://webservice.example.org/">
            <return>Hi, Anish. You are one of the lucky winners. You won a $1000 USD.</return>
        </ns2:SendYourNameAndWinLotteryResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

[image]

**Output (Failure With Custom Fault Message):**

I have tampered the soap body name `SendYourNameAndWinLottery` to an incorrect name `SendYourNameAndWin` for testing.

**Incorrect XML Request Payload:**

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <SendYourNameAndWin xmlns="http://webservice.example.org/">
            <arg0 xmlns="">Anish</arg0>
        </SendYourNameAndWin>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

**Output XML Response:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <S:Body>
        <S:Fault xmlns="" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
            <faultcode xmlns="">random-code</faultcode>
            <faultstring>place your custom error message here.</faultstring>
        </S:Fault>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

[image]

Comment: I will try it, i had tried the handler method as i specified in the question but it didnt work. I will try it again following what you did.

Comment: Hi @Amish, my mistake it was going into the handleFault method of my handler for wrong method names, but for wrong type faults like the ones i added to my question doesnt go into the handle fault method.

Comment: @SalihErikci Let me check it.

Comment: @SalihErikci Can you please add the webservice code? I'm unable to reproduce this on my local.

Comment: @SalihErikci I see for wrong types also, My handler is gracefully working. Please add the code to reproduce this.